# Difference between Collective Matrix Factorization, Joint MF, Linked MF and Coupled MF

Tags: matrices, algorithms, approximation, factoring, matrix-decomposition

Recently I have been browsing some papers about matrix factorization methods used for collaborative filtering (recommender systems) and found four very similar approaches with different names. I'd like to ask whether there is any real difference between them or it is just different naming for the same algorithm. Here they are:

Collective Matrix Factorization (CMF) - Singh, Gordon (2008)

Joint Matrix Factorization (JMF) - Shi, Larson, Hanjalic (2010)

Linked Matrix Factorization (LMF) - O’Connell, Lock (2017)

Coupled Matrix Factorization (CMF) - Almutairi, Sidiropoulos, Karypis (2017)

Thanks a lot!